# Ruby Inserting Image to Rtf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rtf

I have a rtf file.
I want to open that file using Ruby for replacing some placeholders by image.
I was looking around **ruby-rtf**. But it is not suitable for parsing **rtf**, only for creating brand new **rtf**.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution!

First, You have to add a placeholder to your rtf file. For that you have to open rtf file with MS Word and place it in particular position. For example, your placeholder may be named like **@@placeholder@@**.

Second, open saved on step 1 rtf file with notepad so that to clear up a placeholder. Ms word sometimes may add "garbage" tags to your placeholder (**@@pla** rtlch\fcs1 \af39\afs20 \ltrch\fcs0 \b\f39\fs20\insrsid14101935\charrsi **ceholder@@**). You should correct it so that to get **@@placeholder@@**.

Third, use [ruby-rtf](https://github.com/thechrisoshow/rtf).
At last, code for inserting image:

```
# using Document class of ruby-rtf plugin
document = Document.new(nil) 
image = document.image("path_to_image/check.png")

rtf_file = IO.read("path_to_rtf/my.rtf")
rtf_file.gsub!('@@placeholder@@', image.to_rtf)
File.open("#{Rails.root}/my_userdata/new_blank.rtf", "wb") {|f| f.write rtf_file }
```

I hope it will be helpful for someone.